# iPhone 4s reboots on unlock

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, ios, reboot

I have an Apple iPhone 4s running the last version of iOS that can be jailbroken(the one just before 9.1 I think).

Each time I swipe to unlock, it hangs for a second while displaying the pin entry keypad and then reboots. It reboots to safe mode and then back to normal mode.

This has happened before on version 8.4, but it wasn't connected to WiFi then. Restore fixed it.

I want to know how I can fix it without a restore so I can keep root access. I have root SSH access to the device, which is amazingly still connected to the WiFi. I can also use apt tools(apt-get apt-cache dpkg) and I've removed the last installed tweaks(apt-get purge)(DefaultPlayer and iCleaner).

If I have to restore, is there a way to backup over SSH and restore to a jailbreakable version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, always backup.

1. No jailbreakable iOS version is being signed so no, if you restore it you'll lose your jailbreak.

The problem is probably a theme relates package, try disabling winterBoard themes.

I would suggest reinstalling the system anyway because if your safe mode isn't working it means that the private system partition is broken, even if you got it working for some reason it would have loads of problems in the future, unfortunately, you'll lose your jailbreak.

Also, I'd suggest making a backup with iMazing, a great OS X (and windows) tool to manage your iDevices in more detail.

Sorry for that,

Tiferrei

Comment: That typo though :P I suspect you mean lose not love. Do you know how to disable this from the command line? Maybe the package name?

Comment: That's what happens when you answer on a mobile phone. Haha! But well do you have any winterBoard theme installed? If you can access safe mode you can disable them via cydia.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I don't have any themes installed.
I can't even unlock so getting to cydia is kindof hard :P
I'm experienced with Ubuntu so I know how apt works, and thus it would be relatively easy for me to remove things with SSH. I don't have any packages with names containing winterboard or theme.

Comment: I can't backup either, except if there's a way via ssh?

Comment: Would Cydia Impactor work off SSH only? The problem is if I do that and it doesn't work I lose SSH as well

Comment: Yeah, don't try the Impactor, can you enter safe mode?

Comment: Last time I had this issue, I rebooted and tried to enter safe mode with vol down. I also lost or didn't have WiFi last time. As explained in the question, the phone is in regular mode, and when it goes to the apple logo after swiping to unlock, it seems to boot into safe mode since it says that at the top and the background is black. However, when I swipe to unlock, it goes to the apple logo and goes back to regular mode.

Comment: WOW! So that happens already in safe mode? Have you tried manually entering safe mode (it's actually long press on volume up).

Comment: I did last time(sorry for the mistake, but I actually checked last time). I'm afraid of trying because I might lose WiFi and thus SSH(I'm using wpa2 enterprise so it might be encrypted with my passcode)

Comment: Hum I see but it is already restarting when it bounces from and to safe mode after you slide to unlock, so I'd give it a try. Can you back it up throw a laptop?

Comment: Do you know of any way I can backup whatsapp and message chats via SSH?

Comment: And do you think I should first uninstall all the packages I installed? Except ssh of course

Comment: Yes, definitely uninstall all the packages (except system ones and ash)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, crash reporter is sending notifications that springboard has crashed

Comment: Yeah that really sounds like an uncompatible tweak, you should remove all but system ones and ssh

Comment: Did you try plugging it to a computer and backup with iTunes?

Comment: FML rebooted to safe mode no WiFi

Comment: Can you connect it to your iTunes?

Comment: I'm going to try a bit later yes. Then going to try reinstall(upgrade) to the os i am on now. will probably fail.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help anyway, I'll mark your answer as correct because there isn't really anything left to solve now.

Comment: There is a lot of additional valuable information in the comments, can you please integrate them into the answer (where appropriate)?

Comment: No problem! I would suggest reinstalling the system anyway because if your safe mode isn't working it means that the private system partition is broken, even if you got it working for some reason it would have loads of problems in the future, unfortunately, you'll lose your jailbreak. Sorry for that, Tiferrei